# Flexslider in Bigcoomerce for product slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, flexslider, bigcommerce

I have a problem implementing jquery flexslider http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/flexslider in bigcommerce. I want to make my feature products into a slider. I already uploaded the flexslider css and js into my templates. But it doesn't work, the feature products will show all vertically but not in a slider manner.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/template/FlexSlider/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="flexslider">
 <ul class="slides">
  %%Panel.HomeFeaturedProducts%%
 </ul>
</div>


  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

  <!-- FlexSlider -->
  <script defer src="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/template/FlexSlider/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {

    //simple FlexSlider call
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();

    // more complex call
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
         animation: "slide",
         controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
         start: function(slider) {
           $('.total-slides').text(slider.count);
         },
         after: function(slider) {
           $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide);
         }
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

​
Do you have any solutions?

Comment: I see multiple things. Why did you not put the scripts in the head as instructed? Second, Why are you using JavaScript to write a second call to jquery? Third you will want to call flex slider only 1 time (either simple or complex). Lastly you should show what the output of the home featured products panel looks like as you have it configured.

Comment: as scott suggested you are loading flexslider twice which will most likely cause conflicts. I believe the `HomeFeaturedProducts` panel is an unordered list itself, so you probably want to go into the source for that an add you class reference there.

If you're still having issues please update your question with console errors and a live example we can look at.